# Are crosswind landings easier with larger airplanes?

Tags: landing, crosswind

I don't spot an answer to [this question](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mDsozca8gfA&lc=UgzHObDNqVZdj4jr5Dp4AaABAg.8vy5m8pHG2_8yk6vQ9MSuW), so thought to re-post it here. Larger airplanes are heavier and would ostensibly be pushed less by the wind compared to a small airplane? Do larger airplanes have higher crosswind limits then?

Comment: A big difference is the landing speed at touchdown. A 747 touching down at, say, 150 kts needs far less correction than a 172 touching down at 50 knts.

Comment: The relation between weight and side area is fairly constant regardless of size. What matters is landing speed.

Comment: you'd expect the square-cube law to be at work here: weight increases with volume, i.e. the third power of e.g. length, while side area only increases with the second power.

Comment: @GuyInchbald Statistically, wing loading goes up with absolute size, so that relation is not constant.

Comment: @PeterKämpf Yes it does but then statistically landing speed also goes up with absolute size. You can use statistics to prove anything, as the saying goes. There is no fundamental principle why wing loading should be linked to scale, but there very much is so when it comes to speed.

Comment: Another aspect is gusts (and windshear). Heavier airplanes are not affected the same way than lighters one.

Comment: @Guy Inchbald, I don't have the engineering chops to math this out for you, but I am pretty sure the square cube law is the driving factor in large aircraft being more resistant to cross winds.  And landing speed is definitely not a linear function of size.  Compare biz jet landing speed against their larger brethren and I don't think you will see a big difference.

Comment: @MichaelHall You are correct that landing speed is not a linear function of size, thank you for confirming what I just said. The square vs cube issue also confuses the uninitiated but is beyond the scope of these comments.

Comment: "Compare biz jet landing speed against their larger brethren and I don't think you will see a big difference" right!  Because they **cruise** at similar speeds.  But because of the square/cube law, the big plane (at the same speed) will have the advantage landing in a cross wind because of *slower lateral acceleration* once side slip is "kicked out" to land.  It F=ma.  No other "chops" needed here.

Comment: @Michael, the [square-cube law doesn't exist for airplanes](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/32325/what-are-the-physical-laws-for-upscaling-an-rc-model-to-11/32424#32424)! They are not filled with solid material. Consequently, both F and m in F=ma change roughly in proportion, which makes behaviour of similarly-shaped airplanes similar: a big help for engineers.

Comment: @Zeus, good point, thanks.  I guess I sorta forgot airplanes were hollow inside.  I should have just held my tongue on this one!

Comment: "Wing loading" is descriptive of "density" of similar aircraft.  The 747 has twice the wing loading of a Lear 31.  If landing speed is similar, the larger has the advantage.  However, winds certainly did work against the great airships (and square/cube law did not help them).  There are many factors here.  On of the biggest is the ability to "lean" into the wind, hindered by engine nacelles, as John pointed out, and wing length.  High wings are somewhat better here.  The slower, less "dense" aircraft is also more vulnerable to gusts.

Answer (score 14):

Generally yes, since a 20kt crosswind requires considerably less crab angle on final at 135kt compared to 70kt.  The CRJ900 has a demonstrated max crosswind component of 32 kt (If I had those conditions in a 172 and had to put it down, I think I'd just land across the runway).

There is also a significant technique difference once you get above, say, 100,000 lbs, or depending on the engine location.  On heavies where you only have a few degrees of banking margin when the gears touch before the nacelles hit, the technique is to fly wings level crabbing into wind into the flare, and give a large boot of rudder just prior to touchdown, and get it down before you start drifting off to the side (you are effectively in a skidding turn, but there is a delay before you start to actually change direction and you have to achieve ground contact in that delay period, so you make it snappy and don't work on teasing out a smooth touchdown).

On smaller aircraft it's more the traditional sideslip technique, wing low with opposite rudder maintained to keep runway alignment through the flare and touchdown. My jet time was on CRJs and I would land in crosswinds slightly wing low with rudder to keep aligned, similar to landing a glider in a crosswind (it took about 7-9 deg of bank to risk tip contact and a crosswind would never need much more than 3-5, although tip strikes do happen in the CRJ fleet from time to time when pilots have an oops on landing).

Transport airplanes generally don't have a maximum crosswind component as a published limitation, but will list a "demonstrated" crosswind component with the statement "not considered limiting".  It means that it's only the maximum component demonstrated in testing, and you are free to land in stronger ones, but the manufacturer doesn't vouch for the ability of the plane to handle it.

Comment: Flying gliders, we always did what you describe in your second paragraph.

Comment: I fly gliders too and I usually use a bit of slip (why I said "slightly wing down"), but not as much as in a power plane.  With the wings loaded and curving up, the tips are actually quite a ways clear of the ground and you have more bank margin than you'd think.  But yeah you can do it that way if you don't want to lower the wing, but you can't delay the touchdown too long once the rudder is in unless you drop the wing a little.

Comment: Of course. I was taught, and always taught myself, to kick the rudder at the precise moment of touching.

Comment: Another glider pilot chiming in here, I always use the wing-down slip method and try to keep fuselage fully aligned w/ runway centerline throughout the last part of the final.

Comment: @MartinArgerami: I thought you were supposed to touch down crabbed and _then_ kick out the rudder.

Comment: @Sean: if you touch the ground while still crabbed, you are putting a lot of side-stress on the landing gear, which is not desirable.

Comment: @MartinArgerami: If you decrab before touchdown, the crosswind starts blowing you sideways, so you're not only putting a lot of sidestress on the landing gear, you're _also_ going off the side of the runway.

Comment: Of course. My words were literally "kick the rudder at the precise moment of touching".

Comment: Yes if you want to touch down wings level, you have to kick it straight and plant it right there, no holding of off, because if you do, you will immediately start drifting downwind because you are in effect in a skidding turn.  In a heavy airliner, you have several seconds before the drift becomes noticeable, in a sailplane, maybe 1 second.

Answer (score 1):

Flying and landing speed are a function of wing loading, airfoil, ... . The key issue is the landing speed versus the crosswind speed (apparent wind issue).

For gusting crosswinds, having a lot of dihedral (and/or low roll inertia) requires more compensation to handle.