# What's a similar looking aircraft to this illustration?

Tags: aircraft-identification, seaplane

There is this crazy picture of a plane or a boat or both...?

[image: Crazy Plane]

This is just a drawing, I know, but if this aircraft does not exist, is there perhaps a similar looking one in reality?

Comment: I believe the golden bar/pillar in the right foreground is a palm tree trunk.

Comment: For "existence" and what this means you have to post a question on the stack exchange philosophy site.

Comment: It is just a drawing, there is no basis/analog in reality.

Comment: I really like the windows in the wings.

Comment: Just a random comment:  I was at a RC aircraft show and saw a model based off of your drawing.  That thing was a large-scale model (by my estimate 6 or 7 feet wide) and was awesome!

Comment: The airplane depicted is a seaplane which seems to be roughly 70 feet in height. The largest real seaplane in the world seems to be only 40 feet in height: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVIC_AG600

Comment: @TannerSwett It was probably this one https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hughes_H-4_Hercules

Comment: @TannerSwett The [Spruce Goose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hughes_H-4_Hercules) would dispute that claim, and had a total height of 79 feet. The fuselage height on the H-4 was only 30 feet (your 39 foot is total height, probably closer to 18 for the fuselage only).

Comment: I edited the question to make it more relevant and on-topic

Comment: I wonder where the fuel is supposed to be stored, if even the wings are occupied by passengers.

Comment: Very recent, anachronistic answer: https://www.theguardian.com/world/2017/dec/24/ag600-world-largest-amphibious-aircraft-takes-off-in-china

Comment: Given the windows on the leading edge, suggested additional reading: [Why are there so few aircraft that had inhabited wings?](/q/46853)

Answer (score 41):

> **is there perhaps a similar looking one in reality?**

Not really, however the fictional five-deck flying boat depicted is clearly an extrapolation of [flying boats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flying_boat) of the first half of the 20th century.

Visually, the Short Empire class is the most similar:

- domed cockpit at front of hull
- hull chines
- four radial engines mounted in-wing with three-blade propellers
- conventional empennage

[image: Photo of Short Empire flying-boat]
<sup>*Photo of a Short Empire, Public Domain*</sup>

[image: Photo of Short Sunderland]
<sup>*Photo of a Short Sunderland, [CCASA3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/deed.en) [Nick.D](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Short_Sunderland_at_RAF_Museum_London.JPG)*</sup>

The largest all-metal flying boat developed for civilian passenger service was the [Saunders-Roe Princess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saunders-Roe_Princess) which only had two passenger-decks.

[image: Photo of Saunders-Roe Princess]
<sup>*Photo of a Saunders-Roe Princess, Public Domain*</sup>

The largest flying boat was probably the Hughes H-4 Hercules, popularly known as the Spruce Goose. It was designed for military transport (hence no windows). I believe it would have accomodated both troops and military vehicles but probably no more than two decks.

[image: Photo of Hughes H-4 Hercules]
<sup>*Photo of Hughes H-4 Hercules, Public Domain*</sup>

Comment: @RalphJ: There you go. Answer edited. I didn't initially include it because I couldn't really find a picture that showed the similarity well and which wouldn't require obtaining copyright permission. Someone will probably suggest Boeing Clipper next and it will end with arguments about Ekranoplan etc. ;-)

Comment: That's a nice picture, and I ***promise*** I won't suggest going into the Ekranoplan!  Dang, but Hughes' plane was a beast!

Answer (score 37):

This was part of an ad campaign for Timken Roller Bearings in 1946. It is a drawing by George Shepherd.

[image]

Comment: I'm disappointed that it does not exist. Thanks for the answer

Comment: It wouldn't fly from the way it looks.

Comment: It's worth noting that the (magnificent) recent Ghibli animated biopic film **The Wind Rises** features craft something like this in the dream sequences.  (It's a movie about Jiro Horikoshi, the dude who designed the Zero.  The film features both absolutely realistic actual aircraft, and in the dream sequences, strange fantasy aircraft.)

Comment: ***Nice*** find!

Comment: That would be an interesting hotel idea.

Comment: @jjack - Are "would it fly" questions off-topic?

Comment: @Richard I don't know because I'm not a moderator. If you just have a picture it can be difficult to give a reasonable answer, because there is no weight and weight distribution info.

Comment: @jjack: It does look like something the engineers of that time would had designed if they had ever gotten the money to do so. What would make it unflyable is only the absolute size and the [inexorability of scaling laws](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/27401/is-there-a-maximum-possible-size-for-an-airplane/27407#27407).

Comment: @PeterKämpf Yes. Designers and artists conceive of good looking vehicles frequently, just sometimes the realization can cause problems.

Comment: @Fattie If you like _The Wind Rises_ you might also like [_Porco Roso_](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0104652).

Comment: hey @Chloe ! right, I'm very familiar with it!  :)  Happy New Year ...

Comment: Great info here giving the year of the commercial illustration in question.  Interestingly, it seems the Boeing 314 Clipper [basic info on that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_314_Clipper) was retired **that same year**.  What a forward-looking time.

Answer (score 13):

The only successful plane with inhabited wing might have been the Junkers G.38, (which was explored in Germany by the character in studio Ghibli "the Wind Rises".)

[image]

SaRo P.192 "Queen"
[image]

Comment: The holes in the wing for the P.192 are jet engine intakes, no?

Comment: Ah, that's where the engines are. I was wondering.

Comment: the  second plane looks like a space craft, a war space craft to be honest

Comment: It has a fairly brawny look to it. I myself don't see the spacecraft resemblance though.

Comment: Quite right, as I mention above ... *It's worth noting that the (magnificent) recent Ghibli animated biopic film The Wind Rises features craft something like (the OP image) in the dream sequences. (It's a movie about Jiro Horikoshi, the dude who designed the Zero. The film features both absolutely realistic actual aircraft, and in the dream sequences, strange fantasy aircraft.)*  The sequences involving the Junkers G.38 have perfectly realistic exteriors, and the interior is kind of a larger-then-life dream-fantasy.

Answer (score 13):

How About the Dornier Do X
[Dornier Do X on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dornier_Do_X)

[image: Dornier DoX with Early Jupiter Engines]

Comment: @mins perhaps I am missing something, but this seems like a very decent attempt at an answer.

Comment: It seems to have far less in common with the fictional aircraft in the picture in the question than aircraft shown in earlier answers.

Comment: This is the most accurate and informative answer here, in the search for the real equivalent of the illustration in question. Good one!

Comment: That thing held the record for *twenty years* for number of people carried in a plane.

Answer (score 7):

That 5-decker design is outdone, amongst never-built flying boats, by Norman Bel Geddes' *Airliner No. 4* design concept from 1929, with nine decks:
[image]

Comment: Ahhh .. Norman Bel Geddes.  Brilliant answer!